# Minimum of a strange function

Tags: calculus

Given the function built in this way:
$\displaystyle x_1=\frac{1}{x}$  ,
$\displaystyle x_2=x_1^\frac{1}{2x}$  ,  $x_3=x_2^\frac{1}{3x}$ $...$
$x_k=(x_{k-1})^\frac{1}{kx}$
I find a minimum of this function if $k$ is even, the function is instead monononically decreasing if $k$ is odd. How can be explained this behaviour?

Comment: Are you defining the function as $f(x)=\lim_{k\to \infty} x_k$?  Or are you talking about the sequence $\{x_k\}$, which isn't a function but rather a sequence of functions.

Comment: @vadim123: No. I don't. I only observed the $f(x)$ has a minimum when $k$ is even and it doesn't when $k$ is odd, but I don't understand why.

Comment: Given your definitions, what is $f(x)$ exactly? Are you saying $f(1) = x_1, \ldots, f(k) = x_k$?

Comment: @gt6989b: Yes, correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is simply $x_n(x)=x^{^{\displaystyle-\frac1{n!\cdot x^{n-1}}}}$, and it always has a minimum, except for the cases $n=0$ and $n=1$, regardless of the parity of *n*.